# Is it possible to stream Minecraft from a computer to a phone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, streaming, google-play-games, oculus-rift

I'm looking for suitable game for my girlfriend who is pregnant. She isn't really gamer type, but I need something for her to spend her whole time on bed (the doctor said that) I chose Minecraft. But problem is that I only have one laptop. It's Asus G74sx, so I think it can handle multiple minecraft instances at once. I'll play on my it. Meanwhile, I'm planning to buy Google VR 2.0 for my android Phone (Asus Zenfone2). Then I will stream another instance of Minecraft into my phone and she'll play on it.
**Is it possible?**

Comment: Quick question, what version of windows are you running? I don't think it is possible to run 2 instances of MC at once, however the windows 10 edition and the java (normal) version can both run at once. (the Minecraft: Windows 10 edition is not as feature-complete however is a free download if you own the java version)

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1

Comment: well that won't be an option then

Comment: Would it not be easier to get Minecraft: Pocket Edition for your phone?

Comment: Can't you just lend her the laptop?

Comment: @studoku, then what I do? Watch her?

Answer (score 2):

I have thoroughly searched on this issue, and *I don't believe that there is an ideal solution with the problems you have.* At first, I thought about using **Chrome Remote Desktop** to port the monitor of a computer to her phone, but the controls would be horrible. Minecraft: Pocket Edition still isn't in sync with the normal version, so that is off limits as well.

I could only think of one solution which would best match what you need:

### Stream on Twitch

Twitch has a mobile app, and Minecraft has integrated support for it. This solution is perfect for you two. First, you'll have to register an account if you don't have one. The [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Livestreaming) says this:

> To be able to live stream in Minecraft, you first need to have a
> version between 1.7.4 and 1.8.9, inclusive. Then, you need to link
> your Twitch account to your Mojang account [on your Mojang account settings](http://www.mojang.com). After your Twitch
> account is linked, you configure your setting in Main
> Menu/Pause>Options>Broadcast Settings. After that, you are ready to
> stream!

You can stream with the **F6 Button.**

After you get Twitch set up on your computer, install Twitch on your phone. Search for your channel, and your wife can watch you play Minecraft.

For communication, you can have a call play in the background as your wife watches. That way, you can still have conversation as she watches.

Comment: But she only can watch. There is no solution play both?

Comment: I'm assuming you only have the normal Minecraft. If you have Minecraft: Windows 10 (which you can redeem on your Mojang account page), then you should take a look at this: https://mojang.com/2015/09/windows-10-and-pe-gets-cross-play-the-nether-more/

Answer (score -6):

No you can't do that anymore as programmers fixed this issue